# Collapsing a custom jquery accordion on load

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, customization, accordion

There is a custom accordion that came with the HTML theme I'm modifying and I just want to figure out how to collapse them all on load (or have the third option open on load; either one works).

```
(function() {

    var $container = $('.acc-container'),
        $trigger   = $('.acc-trigger');

    $container.hide();
    $trigger.first().addClass('active').next().show();

    var fullWidth = $container.outerWidth(true);
    $trigger.css('width', fullWidth);
    $container.css('width', fullWidth);

    $trigger.on('click', function(e) {
        if( $(this).next().is(':hidden') ) {
            $trigger.removeClass('active').next().slideUp(300);
            $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown(300);
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    // Resize
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        fullWidth = $container.outerWidth(true)
        $trigger.css('width', $trigger.parent().width() );
        $container.css('width', $container.parent().width() );
    });

})();
```

JQuery is not my strength at all, so any help on setting that up would make me happy!

Comment: if all you need is things to be collapsed by default, then set the appropriate css class on the accordion body to the collapsed state. No jquery required.

Answer (score 3):

If you remove, or change:

`$trigger.first().addClass('active').next().show();`

to

`$trigger.get(2).addClass('active').next().show();`

this should select the 3rd one to open, or remove the line to keep them all collapsed.

Comment: beat me to it by a second!

Comment: @Nathan - When I did the above, none of the accordions would open or close.